# Images in recyclerView don't respond to change in theme to dark mode using glide placeholder

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-recyclerview

**RecyclerView**

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
      android:id="@+id/rcv_all_songs"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
     />
```

**Recyclerview Item**

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_song"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_logo"
        app:albumId="@{song.albumId}"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_song_name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="@{song.title}"
        android:textColor="@color/app_name_color"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        app:marquee="@{true}"
        app:selected="@{safeUnbox(viewModel.currentData.id == song.id)}" />
```

**Binding Adapter**

```
@BindingAdapter("app:albumId", "app:recycled", "app:blurred", requireAll = false)
fun setAlbumId(
view: ImageView,
albumId: Long,
recycled: Boolean = false,
blurred: Boolean = false)
{
view.clipToOutline = true
val uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ARTWORK_URI, albumId)
Glide
  .with(view)
  .load(uri)
  .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_default_album_art)
  .transform(CenterCrop(), RoundedCorners(8))
  .into(view)
}
```

**ic_default_album_art**

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:width="30dp"
 android:height="30dp"
 android:viewportWidth="30"
 android:viewportHeight="30">
 <path
  android:pathData="M5,0L25,0A5,5 0,0 1,30 5L30,25A5,5 0,0 1,25 30L5,30A5,5 0,0 1,0  
25L0,5A5,5 0,0 1,5 0z"
  android:fillColor="@color/album_art_default_color"/>
</vector>
```

**colors.xml**

```
<color name="album_art_default_color">#EFEFEF</color>
```

**colors.xml (night)**

```
 <color name="album_art_default_color">#4D4D4D</color>
```

**Change Theme Code**

```
//on click change to light theme
sortView.findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.lyt_light_theme).setOnClickListener {
        storageViewModel.changeTheme(resources.getString(R.string.light))
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)
        builder.dismiss()
    }

    //on click change to dark theme
    sortView.findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.lyt_dark_theme).setOnClickListener {
        storageViewModel.changeTheme(resources.getString(R.string.dark))
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES)
        builder.dismiss()
    }

    //on click change to default theme
    sortView.findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.lyt_default_theme).setOnClickListener {
        storageViewModel.changeTheme(resources.getString(R.string.default_theme))
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM)
        builder.dismiss()
    }
```

I have a switch in my app to dark, light or default (phone theme).

**Problem**

When I switch to light/dark theme; the image don't change the color. It ONLY follows the system/phone theme.

So, when the phone default theme is dark mode, it uses dark color resource and vice versa.

Glide placeholder doesn't support in app light/dark mode resource or what??

Comment: how are you changing themes, add the logic.

Comment: Added. Please see updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you should load placeholder in this way:

```
Glide
  .with(view)
  .load(uri)
  .placeholder(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_default_album_art))
  .transform(CenterCrop(), RoundedCorners(8))
  .into(view)
```